# Cayley docker isn't writing data

Tags: docker, gremlin, cayley

I'm using [or, trying to use] the docker cayley from here: https://github.com/saidimu/cayley-docker

I created a data dir at `/var/lib/apps/cayley/data` and dropped the .cfg file in there that I was instructed to make:

```
{
  "database": "myapp",
  "db_path": "/var/lib/apps/cayley/data",
  "listen_host": "0.0.0.0"
}
```

I ran docker cayley with:

```
docker run -d -p 64210:64210 -v /var/lib/apps/cayley/data/:/data saidimu/cayley:v0.4.0
```

and it runs fine, I'm looking at it's UI in the browser:

[image]

And I add a triple or two, and I get success messages.

Then I go to the query interface and try to list any vertices:

```
> g.V
```

and there is nothing to be found (I think):

```
{
 "result": null
}
```

and there is nothing written in the data directory I created.

Any ideas why data isn't being written?

**Edit:** just to be sure there wasn't something wrong with my data directory, I ran the local volume mounted docker for `neo4j` on the same directory and it saved data correctly. So, that eliminates some possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment yet but I think to obtain results from your query you need to use the All keyword

```
g.V().All() // Print All the vertices
OR
g.V().Limit(20) // Limits the results to 20
```

If that was not your problem I can edit and share my dockerfile which is derived from the same docker-file that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [the lib here](https://github.com/lnshi/node-cayley) to learn more about how to use Cayley's APIs and the data format in Cayley and some other stuff like N-Triples N-quads and RDF:

- [Cayley APIs usages examples (mocha test cases)](https://github.com/lnshi/node-cayley/blob/master/test/apis/callback.js)
- Clearly designed entry-level N-quads data for getting you in: in the project **test/data** directory